# Run Django without server

Tags: python, django

I have a small Django site, `mysite`. I want to be able to run my Django app without running a web server. Instead of using an HTTP client to make requests, I'd like to write something like:

```py
django.run()
result = django_request('/foo/bar')
```

So Django would still do URL parsing, etc, just not serve through UWSGI. Is this reasonable?

My end goal is to benchmark endpoints of my web application end-to-end, except for the I/O.

Comment: Django is a web framework. What you want to do can already be accomplished using plain Python. If you only want to use Django's ORM and templating features, consider using SQLAlchemy and Jinja2.

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I've got a Django application I'd like to benchmark without having a bunch of I/O involved. I'd like to measure the whole stack minus the actual socket stuff (there's no database on the backend, even) which will be noisy.

Comment: I've added more information to the question.

Comment: I/O is one of the factors that have the largest impact on performance in web applications. So, don't expect your results to be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not so worried. Mostly I am comparing some other factors as they relate to Python performance, like PyPy vs CPython, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django test client.

Try the following code in django shell

```
➜ python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 20 2019, 17:12:48) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from django.test import Client

In [2]: c = Client()

In [3]: response = c.get('/blog/')

In [4]: response.status_code
Out[4]: 200

In [5]: response.content
Out[5]: b'\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n\t<title>My Blog</title>\n\t<link href="/static/css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">\n</head>\n<body>\n\t<div id="content">\n\t\t\n\t<h1>My Blog</h1>\n\t\n\t\t<h2>\n\t\t\t<a href="/blog/2019/10/16/my-second-post/">\n\t\t\t\tmy second post\n\t\t\t</a>\n\t\t</h2>\n\t\t<p class="date">\n\t\t\tPublished Oct. 16, 2019, 7:15 a.m. by admin\n\t\t</p>\n\t\t<p>Nice</p>\n\t\n\n\t</div>\n\t<div id="sidebar">\n\t\t<h2>My blog</h2>\n\t\t<p>This is my blog</p>\n\t</div>\n</body>\n</html>'
```

Take a look at the official documentation [Test Client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client)

Comment: Does this still run a server and do all of the requisite socket I/O?

Comment: @tekknolagi I guess no. It directly parses your urlconf and returns the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your own [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/), and invoke them with something like

```
./manage.py my_foo_command --bar=baz --output=baz.txt
```

(The part you write parses your command using Python Argparse)